# How to use POST handler with Restinio?

Tags: c++, windows, rest, http, post

I would like to use c++, Restinio on Windows to handle POST request on the server side. I did not find any useful examples and the syntax is quite hard to understand. Please help me with a basic sample code for this project.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects related to handling HTTP POST requests.

The first and simplest one is specifying a handler for a request. If you use [express-router](https://stiffstream.com/en/docs/restinio/0.6/expressrouter.html) then setting a handler for HTTP POST for a particular path is as simple as:

```
router->http_post("/some/your/path",
   [](const auto & req, const auto & params) {
      ... // Code of your request handler here.
   });
```

But if you don't use express-router then you have to manually check the method of an incoming request:

```
auto your_handler(const restinio::request_handle_t & req) {
   if(restinio::http_method_post() == req->header().method()) {
      ... // Code for handling HTTP POST request.
   }
   ...
}
```

The second and hardest aspect is dealing with POST's body (the body is available via `req->body()` method). There you have to check the `Content-Type` HTTP header and react appropriately:

- if `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you can use RESTinio's `parse_query` helper function for splitting the body into a list of (key,value) pairs. [Here](https://gist.github.com/eao197/87a553ad91c2b4d92485124bb6c6fc01) you can find an example of how it can be done.
- if `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data` then you have to deal with multi-part body. In that case RESTinio's helpers like [detect_boundary_for_multipart_body](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio/blob/v.0.6.5/dev/restinio/helpers/multipart_body.hpp#L480-L500) + [split_multipart_body](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio/blob/v.0.6.5/dev/restinio/helpers/multipart_body.hpp#L38-L75), or [enumerate_parts](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio/blob/v.0.6.5/dev/restinio/helpers/multipart_body.hpp#L628-L704) can be used. See also [content-disposition](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio/blob/v.0.6.5/dev/restinio/helpers/http_field_parsers/content-disposition.hpp#L438-L454) helper.
- if `Content-Type` contains some application-specific value (like `application/json`) then you have to deal with the content of POST's body in application-specific way (something like use JSON parser to deserialize data from body). You can take a look at [restinio-crud-demo](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio-crud-example/blob/master/crud-example/request_processor.cpp#L281-L291) to see that scenario (in very simple form because it's a demo, not a production code).